# unable to start program https localhost the debugger is not properly installed

Tags: visual-studio

I try to run visual studio but can't run

it show unable to start program https localhost the debugger is not properly installed

I attached screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43pBy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably sorted this by now but for anyone else with this issue try deleting the .vs folder in the solution folder, as mentioned in this [developer community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-debugger-is-not-properly-installed/1562903)